# How to construct these functions of a matrix in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, matrix, linear-algebra

I am constructing a tensor that formally depends on a 2x2 matrix `z`. However, the various parts that compose the tensor are constructed from matrices S(z), T(z) and U(z) that are derived from `z` and I'm not sure how to proceed.

Here are the steps to derive S(z), T(z) and U(z). Every matrix z can be decomposed in polar form: z = RU where R is positive semidefinite and U is unitary. By using R and U we define:

1) S(z) = sech(R)

2) T(z) = tanh(R)U

3) U(z) = U

As I have to perform backprop to learn the parameters in z, how do I define S, T and U as functions of z in TensorFlow in a differentiable way? Can I exploit the fact that they are only 2x2 (e.g. to use the eigenvalues explicitly)?

NOTE: A function of a matrix like sech(R) is not the function sech applied element-wise, but rather sech(R) = U' sech(D) U where R = U'DU is the diagonalization of R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way by using the SVD (which is differentiable in TF!):

z = wsv' = (wsw')(wv')= RU

So we have already the diagonalization of R:

S = w sech(s) w'
T = (w tanh(s) w')(wv') = w tanh(s) v'
U = wv'

in code:

```
s, w, v = tf.linalg.svd(z)

S = tf.matmul(w, tf.matmul(tf.linalg.diag(1/tf.math.cosh(s)), w, adjoint_b=True))
T = tf.matmul(w, tf.matmul(tf.linalg.diag(tf.math.tanh(s)), v, adjoint_b=True))
U = tf.matmul(w, v, adjoint_b=True)
```

Here I am not taking advantage of the fact that my matrices are 2x2, which I could do to avoid using the SVD...